# How to get data in R from a very large sql table using a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, odbc

I need to get via ODBC, data from sql table into R for further work.
I do so:

```
library("RODBC")
library("sqldf")
library(here)
library(knitr)
#connect to sql
dbHandle <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=v;database=mybase;trusted_connection=true")

sql <- paste0("/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/
SELECT [ProductKey]
       ,[Price]
       ,[DateKey]
       ,[End_Date]

   FROM my table
where [DateKey]>'2017-01-01'
                ")
df7 <- sqlQuery(dbHandle, sql)
```

But the problem is that this table has a huge number of rows, and when I try to load data into R , I get an error that it does not have enough RAM.

Therefore, the question arose whether it was possible to somehow load data in partitions through a loop, for example, 10,000,000 at a time?

Thus get  all the data. If it is possible, what is the easiest way to do it?
Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Some SQL servers support LIMIT and OFFSET statements, e.g. `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 10000`.  You should use ORDER BY as well, or there's no guarantee that the first n values will be the same on two successive calls.

Comment: There's also `sqlFetch()` in `RODBC`, which allows you to retrieve a small number of rows each time (no more than 1024, I think).

Comment: @user2554330,thank you sqlFetch() works for me. You can do your comment as answer, i all accept it.

Comment: No, I don't know `RODBC` well enough.  You should post your solution if you want.